# Finding uncommented methods in a C# project

Tags: c#, xml-comments

Is there a way to find the number of methods in the assembly which do not have any xml comment on them.

```
public int Sum(int i, int j)
{   
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No

In my point of view, compiler will eliminate the comment code when it compiles the code. If you can use the ildasm.exe tool ship with .net framework to analyze the .exe file (actually it's portable execute file executing after you compile the code) you'll see no information about the comment code.

Comment: An assembly could be compiled with the option to generate the XML comments in a separate file. Then you could do an intersection of the XML with the assembly.

Comment: This if the OP really meant "Assembly" and not "Project".

Comment: Yeap, exactly but there is no tag in XML file which can help you to refer comment code. I think MSDN have a link cref attribute to help developers specify the inner text of XML tag http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837134.aspx